# Why does MAXLOC not respect array bounds?

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, intrinsics

I'm sort of new to Fortran and I'm wondering why MAXLOC (and MINLOC) seemingly ignore array bounds. For example,

```
 integer, dimension(-4:0) :: eps = (/10,20,30,20,10/)
 write(*, *) lbound(eps), " ", ubound(eps)
 write(*, *) maxloc(eps)
```

produces the following output

```
      -4             0
       3
```

I would've expected -2 for MAXLOC. It seems MAXLOC always use 1 as the lower bound, regardless of what you define your array bounds. I'm wondering why that's the case or if I'm doing something wrong. I'm using gfortran 8.2.1.